# Jquery search filter and limit records by object key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, filter

Am trying to make a search in jquery, to filter object by keyword. The problem am having now is when search by "STORE", it show one store more than once. Is okay when i search by "PRODUCT", to show all result from store but for store search i will like to show each store once.

Please is there anyhow i can filter the search by store key so each store is shown in the list once?

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on("keyup", "#search", function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    var sort = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    var count = 0;
    var output = '';
    if (query === '') {
        $('#results').html('');
        return;
    }
    
     var regex = new RegExp(query, "i");
     var data = {
      "result": [
        {"store_name": "Johnson", "store_key": "1A", "product_name": "PHP", "price": 1},
        {"store_name": "Johnson", "store_key": "1A", "product_name": "JAVA", "price": 2},
        {"store_name": "Johnson", "store_key": "1A", "product_name": "VUE", "price": 1},
        {"store_name": "Peter", "store_key": "2A","product_name": "Python", "price": 4},
        {"store_name": "Peter", "store_key": "2A", "product_name": "VUE", "price": 2},
        {"store_name": "Peter", "store_key": "2A", "product_name": "PHP", "price": 4},
        {"store_name": "Peter", "store_key": "2A", "product_name": "JAVA", "price": 3},
        {"store_name": "Paul", "store_key": "3A", "product_name": "JAVA", "price": 3},
        {"store_name": "Paul", "store_key": "3A", "product_name": "PHP", "price": 3},
        {"store_name": "Paul", "store_key": "3A", "product_name": "CSS", "price": 1},
        {"store_name": "Hana", "store_key": "4A", "product_name": "HTML", "price": 1}
      ]
     };
     
     $.each(data.result, function(key, row){
          if (sort === "product" && (row.store_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1) || (row.product_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1)) {

            output += '<div class="item">' + row.product_name + ' <span>' + row.store_name + '</span></div>';

           count++;
          }else  if (sort === "store" && row.store_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1) {
            output += '<div class="item">' + row.store_name + '</div>';
            count++;
          }
               
      });
    $('#results').html(output);
    $('#counter').html("Search Results " + count);
  });
});
```

```css
.item{
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 margin: 3px;
 position: relative;
}
.item span{
 position: absolute;
 right: 4px;
 color: green;
}
#search-box{
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#counter{
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-box">
<input type="search" id="search"/>
PRODUCT <input type="radio" value="product" name="type" checked=""/>
STORE <input type="radio" value="store" name="type"/>
</div>
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: @King11 when you check `STORE` and try to searching for `peter`, it will return multiple results. But i would want it to show peter once instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this, to make the counting, and the adding happens only once for each store.
You simply use a variable as a stopper for repeated stores.

```
var storeOnce = '';
if (sort === "store" && row.store_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1) {            
   if (row.store_name != storeOnce){
       storeOnce = row.store_name;
       output += '<div class="item">' + row.store_name + '</div>';
       count++;
   }
}
```

---

You also should notice that the first if is always true if the second one is true, so when you search for 'p' stores, it would add 'PHP Johnson' to the output.
for that you need to add extra parentheses in the first if after the '&&'

```
if (sort === "product" && ((row.store_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1) || (row.product_name.toLowerCase().search(regex) != -1)))
```

Also this searches for stores and products, not just products, that's why when you search for 'p' products, you will find 'JAVA Peter' as one of the results.
If you want to search only for products, then you should remove the store_name comparison in the if statement.

Comment: Nice job, i didn't know that it will be this easy.